# Can we make glass by heating Martian Soil

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, glass, astrochemistry

I was puzzled by a very interesting question. Can we heat up Martian soil and produce glass just the way we do here on Earth? (the basic way)

---

For info, Martian sand consists of the following -

- $\ce{Na2O}$ — $4~\%$
- $\ce{MgO}$   — $14~\%$
- $\ce{Al2O3}$  — $18~\%$
- $\ce{SiO2}$   — $8~\%$
- $\ce{P2O5}$  — $2~\%$
- $\ce{SO3}$   — $10~\%$
- $\ce{Cl}$ — $2~\%$
- $\ce{K2O}$  — $2~\%$
- $\ce{CaO}$  — $14~\%$
- $\ce{TiO2}$   — $2~\%$
- $\ce{Cr2O3}$  — $2~\%$
- $\ce{MnO}$    — $2~\%$
- $\ce{FeO}$ — $4~\%$
- $\ce{Ni}$   — $8~\%$
- $\ce{Zn}$    — $6~\%$
- $\ce{Br}$    — $2~\%$

I can't see anything out of place here, if we heat it up, the silica
should do it at around $1700~\mathrm{^\circ C}$.

If we can figure out ways to make glass up there then it would be easy for Martian colonization if that is ever going to happen.

Comment: I think this would be closer to a brick than a glass block.

Comment: Note that the sand does not actually contain chemical compounds like $\ce{Na2O}$, $\ce{P2O5}$, $\ce{SO3}$, $\ce{K2O}$ etc. These are just the reference compounds for the elemental analysis.

Comment: Mars was found to have quite large reserves of sulfur, which can be used as a hot binder (at lowly ~200°C) for sand to make a kind of cement. http://arxiv.org/abs/1512.05461

Comment: @Loong - The OP called it "Martian sand" but I think "Martian soil" would probably be more accurate. We now know that Mars did have water, but I'd wonder about Mars having any ancient sandy beaches. My point about a brick is that you'd use less heat to sinter the soil to a brick than you would if you really melted the whole block to form a glass (assuming the composition is amenable which i doubt).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is sorting. Ergo, unless you bring your separator with you, the best areas for finding naturally sorted materials are in outflows such as found in Candor Chasma. Semi-translucent larger grains of quartz-rich phenocrysts might be found in useful quantities. Fusing these with a solar kiln would produce a brick of about 0.125 meters thick that would both shield from the rain of radiation and pass some of the weak Martian sunlight, easing the circadian rhythm of colonists.
Time to temperature (1700 degrees C) still makes production slow. And the loaders and other equipment need to be transported and successfully landed.

See
A Fused Regolith Structure
Ethan W. Cliffton
Proceedings of Space 90
Engineering, Construction, and Operations in Space
ASCE 1990
Albuquerque
and
Candor Chasma Camp Ethan W. Cliffton
Proceedings of Space 88
Engineering, Construction, and Operations in Space
ASCE 1988
Albuquerque